# Amortized time cost of insertion into an Array list

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, amortized-analysis

A dynamically resizing array list will resize when the number of elements reaches a power of two. So, after n elements inserted, we've resized at sizes 1, 2, 4, ... , n. This also means we've copied over into the newly resized array 1, 2, 4, ... , n number of copies. What then is the sum of this sequence? To answer that we see that the sequence written backwards is n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1. Until here I understand what has been said. Here is where my confusion starts, how is this sequence roughly equal to 2n? How do we know this? Once we settle that we can say that n insertions take O(2n) time, but from that how do we deduce that the amortized time for each insertion is O(1).

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Comment: Fun fact: 2 is provably the worst factor for growing an array-list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the estimate,
$$
n + \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{4} + \cdots +1 <n \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots \right) = 2n,
$$
since $1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + \cdots = 2$.

If $n$ insertions take $O(n)$ time, then the amortized time per insertion is $O(n)/n = O(1)$. This is by the *definition* of amortized time. (More accurately, the amortized time is at most $K$ if $n$ insertions take at most $Kn$ time, for *every* $n$.)

Comment: I'm not sure why you've written $\leq$ in the display: sure, it's true but we have equality there, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Just in cast that the sum is actually finite. But you're right, it's misleading.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Ah, I see. Feel free to nuke my edit if you don't think it makes things better. (Maybe it would be better to make the inequality strict, now.)